# How to total smartpy.TMutez type stored as values in smartpy.bigmap?

Tags: smart-contracts, ledger, bigmap, python, smartpy

I have the following `smartpy.bigmap` in smart contract storage:

```
import smartpy as sp
self.data.init(bgmp=sp.bigmap(tkey=sp.TAddress,tvalue=sp.TMutez))
```

I would like to total all the stored `tvalue` so based on the SmartPy [docs](https://smartpy.io/dev/reference.html) I tried:

```
total=sp.tez(0)
sp.for v in self.data.bgmp.values():
    total+=v
```

I then wish to `sp.verify(total>=minAmount<sp.TMutez>)`

When run in the [latest](https://smartpy.io/dev/) SmartPy.io IDE the following error is produced:

```
Error:
Failure: Missing var v in env []
```

If I hardcode `total+=sp.tez(1)` the error becomes:

```
Error:
WrongCondition in line 18: (sp.tez(0) + sp.tez(1)) >= self.data.minAmount
```

I am doubtful that this is a correctly totaled `sp.TMutez` value.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: I am not able to populate the same big map ? can you help?

  poolMemberToDeposit = sp.big_map(tkey = sp.TAddress, tvalue = sp.TMutez)

poolMemberToDeposit[sp.sender] = sp.amount;

can it be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of iterating over all values in a `big_map` in the language to which SmartPy compiles ([Michelson](http://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/michelson.html#operations-on-big-maps)). So it doesn't surprise me that this doesn't work in SmartPy either. Indeed, according the [SmartPy documentation](https://smartpy.io/dev/reference.html#_container_access):

> e.values(): Returns the list of values of a map, sorted by keys.

Here, I presume that `map` refers exclusively to normal, "simple" maps and not `big_map`s.

However, there is probably some other way of solving your problem. For instance, you can keep track of the big_map's total in a separate variable, and update it each time the `big_map` is updated.

Comment: thanks for this. going to track the total with an extra variable

Answer (score 1):

@arvidj is right of course and you cannot iterate on a bigmap. You need to keep your sum in the storage.

You also have another error: if it was a map, you would still need to use a local variable to accumulate the sum. This is introduced by `total = sp.newLocal('total', ...)`. 
What the error is telling you is that your `v` is escaping it`s scope.
With 1, we could also analyze the mistake but don't currently. The only way to currently see it is to check the generated script (in the output panel) which shows a code that you don't expect.

Then, with local variables. To set a local variable (introduced by newLocal) you currently need to use `total.set(...)`. It will be changed to `total.value = ...` because we observe that the current syntax is too confusing.